# DrRacket Combining Lists

Tags: racket, cartesian-product

I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction:
I am looking two produce all possible combinations of items in two lists:
Example:
Given the lists '(symbol1 symbol2) and '(1 2), I am looking to produce:
(list (list 'symbol1 1) (list 'symbol1 2) (list 'symbol2 1)(list symbol2 2))

My code thus far is:

```
    (define (combiner list1 list2)
    (list
      (foldr (lambda (a b) (foldr (lambda (c d) (list a c)) empty list1)) empty list2)
      (foldr (lambda (a b) (foldr (lambda (c d) (list b d)) empty list1)) empty list2)))
```

This clearly isn't working, and neither are a few other methods I've tried. I am having trouble working with the implicit recursion on two lists - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of another possible way to solve the problem. Here's a hint:

```
(define (combiner list1 list2)
  (define (combine l1 l2)
    (cond ((empty? l1) empty)
          ((empty? l2) XXX)
          (else (cons YYY
                      ZZZ))))
  (combine list1 list2))
```

In the above piece of code, you'll have to figure out the answer to three questions:

- `XXX` How do you advance the recursion when you've finished iterating over the second list, but the first list still has elements, and also you want to advance one element in the first list?
- `YYY` How would you combine an element from the first list with an element from the second list?
- `ZZZ` How do you advance the recursion when both lists still have elements left, but at this point you're only interested in advancing over the second list?

One last hint: notice that at some point you need to "restart" the second list, for that, you can refer to the original `list2`, which has not changed at all.

I hope this helps you, I don't want to give you a straight answer (yet) - I want you to figure out the solution by yourself.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who submitted help! Oscar, I agree that that's a great solution but I need to find one with lambda and foldr. Luckily I managed to work it out... Kept wrapping one inside the other! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking at here is recursion on two complex arguments, [section 17](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-22.html#node_chap_17) of How To Design Programs. If you want another hint, I'll tell you which of the three cases this is.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for reply. I've taken a look and I believe I'm dealing with case 3. I've designed a recursive function to tackle this sort of problem before but I'm not seeing how to do this using lambda and foldr. I see how foldr handles recursion intrinsically, but I'm just not seeing how to get it to work on two lists at the same time.

Comment: I think I need to sleep on this a little bit!

Comment: I've figured out how to get 
        
        (list (list 'symbol1 1) (list 'symbol1 2))

Comment: Nope, not case 3; iirc, it's case 1; for each element in the first list, you want to pair it with all the elements in the second. In fact, it looks like your comment above shows that you've discovered this already.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one thing that can add to confusion here is the liberal use of `list`. I'm going to start approaching your problem using Haskell notation for types. `::` means "has type", and `[Foo]` means "list of Foo".

```
list1 :: [Symbol]
list2 :: [Number]
type Pair = (Symbol, Number)
(combiner list1 list2) :: [Pair]
```

Now it looks like you want to approach this problem with a `foldr` over list2.

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

foldr requires a `step :: a -> b -> b` and a `start :: b`. Since we want the final result to be a `[Pair]`, that means that `b = [Pair]`. `start` will probably be the empty list, then. Since list2 fills the `[a]` slot, that means that `a = Number`. Therefore for our problem, `step :: Number -> [Pair] -> [Pair]`

```
combiner :: [Symbol] -> [Number] -> [Pair]
combiner list1 list2 = foldr step start list2
  where step :: Number -> [Pair] -> [Pair]
        step a b = undefined
        start = []
```

So far this is the same as the `foldr` that you wrote, except I haven't defined the `step` yet. So what is the step function? From the type, we know it must take a `Number` and a `[Pair]` and produce a `[Pair]`. But what do these inputs mean? Well the `Number` input will be some element of `list2`. And the `[Pair]` input will be the "result of the fold so far". **So we'll want to take our `Number`, and do *something* to create the `Pair`s for it, and then slap those onto the result so far.** This is the point at which my code begins to differ from yours.

```
step a b = append (doSomething a) b
doSomething :: Number -> [Pair]
doSomething a = undefined
```

Since you, using Racket, will probably define `doSomething` as an anonymous function, that means `list1` is in scope. (Since it is in the where clause of the function in Haskell, it is in scope). You will probably use that list to generate the combinations.

```
doSomething a = ... a ... list1 ...
```

Implementing `doSomething` is left as an exercise for the reader, as is translating back into Racket. Note that the type signature for the Haskell function that I'm defining here, `combiner`, can be generalized to `[a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`.